# SqlServerCE: TableAdapter + @@identity

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0

How do I get id of an insert query? Simple:

```
insert into Ex(sth) values("value");
select @@identity
```

does not work. When I try to ExecuteScalar or any other I get exception: {"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 95,Token in error = select ]"}.

I remind this is the CE edition. I'm using MSVS2010

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net SQL CE client does not support multiple statements.
You need to use two separate `SqlCeCommand`s.

Comment: well... but you cannot do it in separated queries while you get null from the Select. Are there any other solutions to the problem? I mean - getting id previously inserted row.

Comment: I'm not sure.  You could use a GUID (from the client) instead.

Comment: Ok, got it but still smth is remaining :/ TableAdapter automaticaly closes its connection after query, so quering for @@identity doesn't make any sense - the query has to be made on the same connection - that's what I made. Unfortunately you lose the benefits of the visual editor, while you have to write additional function by your own ;(

Answer (score 0):

TableAdapter (.NET 4) closes connection after command execution only when it was closed before command execution. So use something like this:

```
try
            {
                if (_tasksAdapter.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    _tasksAdapter.Connection.Open();

                _tasksAdapter.InsertNew(_partitionedFile.Uid, _partitionedFile.Checksum);
                _dbId = (int)_tasksAdapter.GetIdentity().Value;
            }
            finally
            {                    
                if (_tasksAdapter.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    _tasksAdapter.Connection.Close();
            }
```

where methods InsertNew performs INSERT command and GetIdentity() method performs SELECT @@IDENTITY.